# MutationObserver — only do something if nodes added, not removed

Tags: javascript

I have a MutationObserver that I'm using like so—

```
var config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  characterData: false,
  subtree: true
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  //need to call function1() only when nodes are ADDED, not removed
});

var startObserving = function () {
  target = document.getElementsByClassName("message-container")[0];
  observer.observe(target, config);
}
```

I need to both add and remove elements to/from the container that the `MutationObserver` is watching, but I only want to execute `function1()` when nodes are added. Is there a way to do this? I've been reading the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) article but can't think of a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to check the `addedNodes` property on each of the `mutations` object to determine if elements were added. You’ll probably also want to validate that the `type` is `childList`.

Check out the [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) page on the MDN.

Something like

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  var hasUpdates = false;

  for (var index = 0; index < mutations.length; index++) {
    var mutation = mutations[index];

    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length) { 
      hasUpdates = true;

      break;
    }
  }

  if (hasUpdates) {
    function1();
  }
});
```

Comment: well this ran my function multiple times but I just ended up using your answer but adding a boolean to check if "added == true" and then called my functions outside of the for loop and it works like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't know if you needed to pass in any info about what specifically changed or just run it once, but I'm glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

I prefer do this using observer options `childList` and `subtree`. Then observer filtering changes

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    // do something
});

observer.observe(node, {
    childList: true, // detecting childList changes
    subtree: true // detecing in childs
});
```